# Firebase test lab - Stuck at Uploading app APK

Tags: firebase, android-studio, android-espresso, ui-testing, firebase-test-lab

I'm trying to making a UI test with Firebase test lab from Android studio.

But I'm still stuck on the step:  Uploading app APK ...

[image]

Anyone already faced this issue?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: If this is a persistent problem, contact Firebase support for assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I just did, waiting for the response. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was about my android studio and gradle version.
They were not up-to-date.

So I set Android studio 3.6.2 and gradle 3.6.2 and now i'm ,not stuck anymore !